# How to make the string variable in Lua

Tags: lua

I am writing a scrips in Lua and the scrips always show the string in table like this

```
order = { apple="0@1@2"}
print(order["apple"])
```

because its frequently showed i would like to create a function to cover it all

```
function getnumber(a,apple)
a=tonumber(order["apple"])
print(a)
end
```

but I find out that "apple" is not variable so i tried tostring like order[tostring(apple)] but is still doesnt work( attempt to call global 'string' (a table value)
stack traceback) could someone teach me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the deal with `tonumber()` sometimes being there?

Answer (score 1):

```
order = { apple="0@1@2"}

function getnumber(key)
    return (order[key])
end

print(getnumber("apple"))
```

This returns:

`0@1@2`

Or assign it to a variable to use later:

`value = getnumber("apple")`

Comment: Ty it helps, But how about if  I really wanna make the string variable, what should i do?

Comment: @ChengEric It is already a string. You can see this by adding `print(type(value))` after the above. So, `getNumber()` should probably be renamed.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your function parameters are correct, this code will do the same thing as your first code snippet:

```
function getnumber(a, apple)
  _G.a = {[apple] = "0@1@2"}
  print(a[apple])
end

getnumber('order', 'apple')
```

However, this looks so strange, I can't help but wonder if that's what you really want. Maybe you could post more examples of your existing code so we can see what they have in common that should be factored out to a function.